# How to convert a spark dataframe array of strings to vector in python

Tags: arrays, apache-spark, dataframe, vector, user-defined-functions

I have a table test_tbl:

```
+-----------------+--------------+--------------+--+
| test_tbl.label  | test_tbl.f1  | test_tbl.f2  |
+-----------------+--------------+--------------+--+
| 0               | a            | b            |
| 1               | c            | d            |
+-----------------+--------------+--------------+--+
```

I want to combine columns f1 and f2 as a vector with the following pyspark code:

```
arr_to_vector = udf(lambda a: Vectors.dense(a), VectorUDT())
df = sqlContext.sql("""SELECT label,array(f1, f2) as features                         
                         FROM test_tbl""")
df_vector = df.select(df["label"], 
arr_to_vector(df["features"]).alias("features"))
df_vector.show()
```

Then, I got the error:
    ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

However, if I change the values of f1 and f2 in the table to be numbers (although the column data type is defined as string) like:

```
+-----------------+--------------+--------------+--+
| test_tbl.label  | test_tbl.f1  | test_tbl.f2  |
+-----------------+--------------+--------------+--+
| 0               | 0.1          | 0.2          |
| 1               | 0.3          | 0.4          |
+-----------------+--------------+--------------+--+
```

The error is gone and the udf works fine.

Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using StringIndexer to convert categorical variables into float.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/ml-features.html#stringindexer

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(0, "a"), (1, "b"), (2, "c"), (3, "a"), (4, "a"), (5, "c")],
    ["id", "category"])

indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol="category", outputCol="categoryIndex")
indexed = indexer.fit(df).transform(df)
indexed.show()
```

Comment: You should include an example of the use that would answer the question. Links die, in time, and then your answer will provide no information.